# CMake Error: CMAKE_MODULE_PATH does not contain Findcatkin.cmake

Tags: rviz, rosdep, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to install rviz from source. It seems a lot of packages are missing from my installation of ROS from source. So, I worked my way through the github repository, cloned the corresponding folders, copied them into /opt/ros/..., and ran cmake to build the packages from source. This worked fine until the package "genpy" where cmake gives the following error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findcatkin.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "catkin", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "catkin" with any
  of the following names:

    catkinConfig.cmake
    catkin-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "catkin" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "catkin_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "catkin"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/68767/cmake-error:-cmake_module_path-does-not-contain-findcatkin.cmake/) by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 529 on 2013-07-24

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [saba426](https://answers.ros.org/users/23823/saba426/) on 2015-09-10**:
Were you able to fix this problem? I get the same error with suitesparse.

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2017-09-25**:
I'm also having this issue, has anyone found a working solution? (nothing listed below works for me)

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-09-25**:
@M@t this is a very old solved question. It doesn't make sense to try to revive this. Please ask your question as a new question with full details on how to reproduce it. http://wiki.ros.org/Support

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2017-09-25**:
There seems to already be a few questions with this same issue that exist, such as [this question](https://answers.ros.org/question/250719/unable-to-open-catkin-workspace-with-qt-creator/), so I'm reluctant to open a duplicate question. Unfortunately, the answer given doesn't work for me.

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2017-09-25**:
I'll keep searching for an answer, and if I find one I'll reopen the question linked above and give a full answer. If not, I'll take your suggestion and open a fresh question.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-09-25**:
The problem you're running into is very generic. The catkinConfig.cmake is not on your CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH. The question is why it's not on your path. The only way to know that is to have enough information to reproduce the problem you are having exactly, since it's likely a procedural error.

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2017-09-25**:
I see, I'll start collecting everything I need to make a proper question. Thanks for the help, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

map_msgs is a ROS package, so you need to install map_msgs from source, it is not installed by rosdep: find the github repository that it is in here: http://ros.org/wiki/map_msgs

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on 2013-07-24**:
I think this just leads to a cycle of problems (see above).

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-07-24**:
Did you build it ? I think you might need to compile those files...

**Comment by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on 2013-07-25**:
see above. I adjusted the problem description to the most recent problem - I hope that's fine.

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-07-25**:
Did you try rosmake tools as well ? Maybe this package has not been catkinised yet...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i get the same problem for catkin_simple
By not providing "Findcatkin_simple.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
"catkin_simple", but CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "catkin_simple"
with any of the following names:

```
catkin_simpleConfig.cmake
catkin_simple-config.cmake
```

Add the installation prefix of "catkin_simple" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"catkin_simple_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
"catkin_simple" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
has been installed.

---

Originally posted by [Craig](https://answers.ros.org/users/26391/craig/) with karma: 78 on 2016-03-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jjsmonkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/27358/jjsmonkey/) on 2016-07-01**:
have you solved the problem? I got the same problem.

**Comment by [amaTMR](https://answers.ros.org/users/70166/amatmr/) on 2021-05-28**:
This helped me

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH _PATH "/opt/ros/noetic;${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}")

**Comment by [Mgl_H838](https://answers.ros.org/users/88948/mgl_h838/) on 2021-11-05**:
HI @amaTMR, could you be a bit more specific for this newbie here, please?